# Ipyleaflet: how to use right-click in notebook in browser?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, ipyleaflet

**Context:**

I have an interactive map. If you 'right-click' inside a shape (outlined in bright green), it highlights this shape in blue and appends information related to the shape, to a list (as a geopandas dataframe). (see picture) [image]

**Problem:**

This code works on vscode, but if I used a browser-based notebook, 'right-click' (`contextmenu` in the code) triggers the popup of the page's options (see picture) [image].

While the information is still appended to my list of geopandas dataframes, it does not highlight the shape in blue.

**Ideas:**

I thought of 2 ways of getting rid of this issue:

- Change the right-click interaction to a middle-click (or typing a letter on the keyboard)
- Remove the popup of the webpage on right-click

But with `ipyleaflet`, a 'left-click' and a 'middle click' (click with the scroll wheel) are not possible to distinguish one from the other.

Any idea about how I could tackle this issue ?

**Code:**

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, WMSLayer, basemaps
from ipywidgets import HTML
from owslib.wms import WebMapService


# Address for the wms layer
wms_url = "https://glims.org/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&"
wms_layer = WMSLayer(
    url=wms_url,
    layers='GLIMS:RGI',
    transparent=True,
    format='image/png'
)


# Create a Pandas DataFrame with X and Y coordinates
#data = pd.DataFrame({'X': list(fx_map[::50]), 'Y': list(fy_map[::50])})

# Map and label widgets
map = ipyl.Map(basemap=basemaps.Esri.WorldImagery, center=(0, 0), zoom=2)
label = ipyw.Label(layout=ipyw.Layout(width="100%"))

# Create a list to store clicked URLs
urls = []

wms = WebMapService(wms_url)

# Initialize a list to store the geopandas dataframes
gdf_list = []

# Create a function to handle click events
def click_handler(properties=None, **kwargs):
    
    
    # Uncomment if you want to print all possible operations with mouse
    #print(kwargs.get('type'))   

    # If right-click, then do all that
    if kwargs.get('type') == 'contextmenu':
        latlon = kwargs.get('coordinates')
        lat, lon = latlon[0], latlon[1]
        print(f"Clicked at (Lat: {lat}, Lon: {lon})")
        
        # Get feature info of the shape clicked-on
        response = wms.getfeatureinfo(
            layers=['GLIMS:RGI'],
            srs='EPSG:4326',
            bbox=(lon-0.001,lat-0.001,lon+0.001,lat+0.001),
            size=(1,1),
            format='image/jpeg',
            query_layers=['GLIMS:RGI'],
            info_format="application/json",
            xy=(0,0))

        # Download the features in a geopandas dataframe
        df = gpd.read_file(response)
        # Append the dataframe to the list of dataframes
        gdf_list.append(df)  

        # If shape has no info the script still runs
        try:
            print(f"You have selected the glacier {df['NAME'].values[0]}, ID: {df['id'].values[0]} ")
        except:
            print(f"This glacier is not recognized by the RGI (maybe an ice-shelf ?) -> Choose another one")

        # PCreate the layer for the blue shape that was clicked on
        geo_data = GeoData(geo_dataframe = df,
                   style={'color': 'black', 'fillColor': '#3366cc', 'opacity':0.05, 'weight':1.9, 'dashArray':'2', 'fillOpacity':0.6},
                   hover_style={'fillColor': 'blue' , 'fillOpacity': 0.2},
                   name = 'Glacier')
        # Add the blue shape to the map
        map.add_layer(geo_data)
        gdf_list.append(df)  

        



# Enable zoom when scrolling with the mouse
map.scroll_wheel_zoom = True
ipyw.VBox([map, label])


# Add the WMS layer to the map
map.add_layer(wms_layer)

# Add the click event handler to the map
map.on_interaction(click_handler)

map
```